# How to import xml in PostgreSQL?

Tags: xml, database, postgresql

I installed postgresql on my pc with Windows.
Use postgresql using the prompt command line.
I'm studying how to import an XML file into PostgreSQL .
but I can not find how to do it.
for example in oracle it does with sqlloader . what is the equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not the specify version number of PostgreSQL
2. There is no command/program I know of, but you can use `pg_read_file` function in PostgreSQL 8.3 – 9.0, or `pg_read_binary_file` since PostgreSQL 9.1. Bear in mind both have their limitations (e.g. administrator privileges are needed to run them)
3. With `pg_read_binary_file` you have to issue an SQL statement like:

   SELECT XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(pg_read_binary_file('< YourFilaneme>'), '< YourCharacterEncoding >'));

UTF8 is the most usual value for `<YourCharacterEncoding >`.

4. See [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-admin.html) for the details of `pg_read_binary_file` and `pg_read_file`